# coupled non linear different equations in matrix form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods, quantum-computation

Consider following differential equation of the form,
$[\frac{d^2}{dx_1^2}+\frac{d^2}{dx_2^2}+x_1^2+x_2^2+gx_1^2x_2^2+x_1^4+x_2^4]u(x_1,x_2)=E u(x_1,x_2),$
where $g$ is the coupling constant. Please can anybody tell me what is an efficient algorithm to solve the system for $u(x_1,x_2)$.
($E$ are the Eigenvalues and $u(x_1,x_2)$ are the eigenfunctions).

Comment: I see no equation !

Comment: This is actually a linear DE. Linearity is not determined by how the independent variables $(x_1, x_2)$ show up, but how the *dependent* variables show up. Question: should the derivatives be partial derivatives? And can you add more context, such as what work you've done on the problem?